# cannot understand document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0]; code javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var clear = document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0];
```

Explain this line of JavaScript please .
Class name is 'clear'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: Gets the first element in an array of `HTMLElement` with the class `clear`

Comment: what is the use of this '[0]'

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('clear')` returns an array (notice the *s* at `getElements`. `document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0]` is the first "cell" of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This statement returns an array of all your HTML elements that have the class 'clear'. The [0] selects the first item of this array.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('clear')` returns all elements which have `class='clear'`. `[0]` if only the first one

```js
var clear = document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[0];
console.log(clear); // returns the element 0 : <div class='clear'>A</div>


var clear2 = document.getElementsByClassName('clear')[1];
console.log(clear2); // returns the element 1 : <div class='clear'>B</div>
```

```html
<div class='clear'>A</div>
<div class='clear'>B</div>
```